# why does the single crystal ferroelectric have a different hysteresis curve compared to polycrystalline ferroelectric?

Tags: materials, ceramics

For the ferroelectric hysteresis curve, is there a reason why single crystal ferroelectrics have a 'hard' ferroelectric hysteresis curve compared to 'soft' ferroelectric hysteresis curve for polycrystalline ferroelectrics?

Comment: If the title length is comparable to the body length, the former is too long and the latter too short.

Comment: Crystals of polycrystallic materials do not have uniform orientation of their crystal lattices and it is well known crystallic materials have usually anisotropic properties.

Comment: @Poutnik - and being ferroelectric requires the lack of a symmetry center

Comment: Keywords to complememt «ferroelectric hysteresis»: Curie temperature, Néels temperature, Weiss domains. And *conceptually*, there are similarities between domains within a single crystal (note that twinning may occur) , individual crystals, or large grains.

Comment: @JonCuster Nice to see an echo of crystallography here.